# Execute a function as a different account in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, credentials

Let's say there is the admin who has written an apps script code and the admin credentials are
username - admin@gmail.com
password - admin_password

It's deployed as a web app and the user can access the app with their google account

The app has 2 functions which are related to google drive (shared drive)
Now I want the first function to run with the credentials of the user accessing the app and the second function to run under the credentials of the admin, but I don't want to share the admin credentials with the end user

How can this be achieved with apps script ?

Can we sign in using a code for the admin and hide the code to the end user ?

I tried the execute as admin function in apps script but that asks for the credentials of the admin

Comment: Your going to have to login as that user, directly and then authorize the application.    Google doesn't want you 1. sharing login and password.  2. using client login in code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.